# One companies network is unable to access my Google App Engine website, anyone else having this issue?

Tags: google-app-engine

The website is accessible to everyone else and all the online websites that check to see if your website is accessible come back positive.

This one organization, who used to be able to access the website, was all of a sudden unable to access the website the other day. They've tried from multiple computers in their organization, but it just keeps telling them that the website isn't able to be found. The only conclusion I can come to is an issue with the way their network is setup; cache, DNS, needs to be whitelisted? I have no way of knowing. Their IT people say they have no idea and it's really hard to help solve an issue with a network I have no access to.

I'm think the following could be causing the problem, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/?hl=en#static-ip

Even knowing all this, I have no idea how to resolve it. Is it possible to setup a dedicated instance to the website and attach an IP address to that instance and serve them a single instance through maybe, backdoor.website.com or something similar? Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

Comment: I did have something similar about a month ago, but I don't know what happened and don't have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

On your GAE app side make sure you don't have their network blacklisted in a  [DOS protection](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/?hl=en#blacklists) configuration.

On their network side first check if the host+domain name of your server resolves to one (or more) IP addresses. If it doesn't then their DNS service needs to be investigated (the issue could be either inside their network in the DNS caching/forwarding configs, or outside at one of their external DNS providers).

If DNS resolving produces some IP addresses check those addresses specifically (instead of using your server's host+domain name) on your network (assuming your network doesn't have outgoing restrictions). If this doesn't work the issue is likely a DNS mapping problem. This info should help their IT people debug their DNS service.

Otherwise it's most likely a networking issue. Check the logs of your app, looking for requests from their network's external IP address(es). If you don't see such requests it means their request don't make it to your app. If you see the requests it means your app's replies don't make it back to them. 
This info could help their IT people debug their network or their internet provider service looking for possible routing issues, access control list (ACL) configs, etc.